# C++ - compiling error

Tags: c++, compilation

I'm trying to compile the following program but it's not working and I don't know why.
The compiler doesn't know the class Player defined in Player.hh

```
Update.cpp:19:39: error: expected type-specifier before ‘Player’
Graphic/Update.cpp:19:39: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘Player’
Graphic/Update.cpp:19:39: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘Player’
Graphic/Update.cpp:19:47: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
Graphic/Update.cpp:19:67: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
make: *** [Graphic/Update.o] Error 1
```

My code (.cpp) :

```
#include "Player.hh"
#include "Update.hh"

Update::Update()
{
  creator[NOTHING] = &Update::Nothing;
  creator[WALLFIX] = &Update::Wallfix;
  creator[WALLBRK] = &Update::Wallbrk;
  creator[PLAYER] = &Update::Player;
  creator[AI] = &Update::Ai;
}

Update::~Update()
{
}

bool          Update::init_map(std::vector<AObject *> &objects, Map &map, const std::vector<IElements *> &players)
{
  Player      *player = (dynamic_cast<Player *> (players.front())); // this line cause the error

 (void)map;
 for (int i = (player->getY() - 10); i < player->getY() + 10; ++i)
 for (int j = (player->getX() - 10); j < player->getX() + 10; ++j)
      {
        AObject *obj;

        if ((obj = (this->*creator[NOTHING])(i, j)) == NULL)
          return false;
        objects.push_back(obj);
      }
  return true;
}
```

The file Player.hh inherit from the abstract class ABro.hh

```
#ifndef PLAYER_HH_
# define PLAYER_HH_

# include "ABro.hh"

class Player
  : public ABro
{
public:
  Player(TypeElements elem);
  ~Player();
  Player(Player const & other);
  Player & operator=(Player const & other);
};

#endif /* !PLAYER_HH_ */
```

Comment: Your parameter list for `Update::init_map` contains a stray "\" - can you confirm whether or not it's like this in your program?

Comment: It's like this in my program cause of my terminal.

Comment: Format the program text so that has no special characters necessary. This avoids wrong assumptions.

Comment: Can you show player.hh?

Comment: Does the Update class contain a field or method named Player? That would cause this issue. If that's not it I would try simplifying the example down to something less complex, such as putting just that one offending line in its own standalone function with the 'players' vector declared as a local variable.

Comment: You say `ABro` is an abstract class, so I'd assume it's got at least one method with `= 0` in it. Your `Player` class (at least the bit you've shown), doesn't seem to have any overridden virtual methods. Could that be the problem? Another thing to note, some consider it good practice to declare destructors as `virtual` when used in an inheritance hierarchy, but it's mostly necessary when it's a polymorphic relationship. This is to make sure any allocated memory gets properly deallocated.

Comment: Ok it's working now thank's to charlie. I had a function named "Player" in Update so it was a cause of the conflict with the class player